# Xamarin.ios Today Extension from Visual Studio

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, today-extension

I am having the hardest time getting this simple task accomplished, and all I'm testing right now is the sample!

Following [this tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_extensions/), I was able to successfully create a Today Extension from Xamarin Studio directly on my mac. However, following the same process in Visual Studio 2015 on my Win 10 PC, I get absolutely nothing (as far as a today extension).

I attempted several "fixes". Firstly I tried simply copying the completed and working app from the mac to windows. Open it in VS, app successfully builds and deploys to simulator. A today extension is actually available, but it'll never load my view. It just says "Unable to Load". I tried both the storyboard and hard coded method, no bueno. Looking into the System Log for the simulator I see something about a Hub connection error and unsupported XPC object os_xpc_dic.

I played around with it more and more and eventually got it to work on the simulator. I had both CFBundleDisplayName and CFBundleName with a hyphen in it (app - ext name). After removing this AND deploying to an entirely different ios device simulator (6 plus rather than 6s plus), the today extension finally displayed the default hello world text.

I then tried to deploy this to my physical device, but alas, still the "Unable to Load" message. Thinking it had something to do with a "dirty" installation of the app, I attempted a variety of clean/re-builds along with deleting and re-adding the app to the device. I even tried changing the CFBundleName and DisplayName along with the CFBundleIdentifier, but nothing is working!!!!

Looking into the Device Log at the time the today widget center is loaded, this is what I see:

> • Will update publication state of
>   com.TexasDominos.ITSupport.AlertExtension visibilityChanged: 1
>   contentStateChanged: 0 insertAtTop: 0 notifyingObservers: 1
>
> • Publication state of com.TexasDominos.ITSupport.AlertExtension
>   isVisible: 1 hasContent: 1
>
> • com.TexasDominos.ITSupport.AlertExtension: 0x1576e8570; container:
>   WGMajorListViewController Begin sequence with reason: appearance
>   transition
>
> • com.TexasDominos.ITSupport.AlertExtension: 0x1576e8570; container:
>   WGMajorListViewController Aborting active life cycle sequence:
>
> • com.TexasDominos.ITSupport.AlertExtension: 0x1576e8570; container:
>   WGMajorListViewController Aborting sequence as argument sequence
>   (WGWidgetLifeCycleSequence: 0x170a35740; sequenceID:
>   com.TexasDominos.ITSupport.AlertExtension.WGMajorListViewController.4/20/17,
>   11:31:00 AM; currentState:
>   WGWidgetLifeCycleSequenceStateDidRequestRemoteView) isn't in expected
>   range (WGWidgetLifeCycleSequenceStateDidConnectRemoteView
>   \M-b\M^@\M^S\M-B\240WGWidgetLifeCycleSequenceStateRemoteViewRevealed)
>
> • com.TexasDominos.ITSupport.AlertExtension: 0x1576e8570; container:
>   WGMajorListViewController Initiating new life cycle sequence:
>   'WGWidgetLifeCycleSequence: 0x170a35740; sequenceID:
>   com.TexasDominos.ITSupport.AlertExtension.WGMajorListViewController.4/20/17,
>   11:31:00 AM; currentState: WGWidgetLifeCycleSequenceStateQuiescent'
>
> • com.TexasDominos.ITSupport.AlertExtension: 0x1576e8570; container:
>   WGMajorListViewController Connection requested with reason:
>   'appearance transition'
>
> • com.TexasDominos.ITSupport.AlertExtension: 0x1576e8570; container:
>   WGMajorListViewController Can't request remote view controller that is
>   blacklisted
>
> • com.TexasDominos.ITSupport.AlertExtension: 0x1576e8570; container:
>   WGMajorListViewController Will request remote view controller

I am so confused by this issue and can't seem to do anything to correct this on the physical device. Something tells me if I were to completely wipe my physical device, the extension would start to work properly since it's working from a clean installation on the simulator as well. But there is no way in a hell I'm going to wipe my device for what should be a simple fix.

Any tips?

Gerneio

*Note: I also tried creating and adding the today extension from directly within VS, but I received even more issues. I had to manually change the build order and dependencies, as well as the reference from the container to the extension. Even still, the extension wouldn't show up at all. The above route showed more promise, at first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe my theory of wiping all the app data from the phone itself was correct. I was able to get the extension working properly by...

1. Delete the app from the device.
2. Re-install the initial blank app from Xcode that Xamarin.ios guides have you create to initially create and deploy the provisioning profile.
3. Delete the blank app.
4. Install your app from VS.

Now my today extension shows up properly! What a hassle.

Side Note: For whatever reasons after a few deploys, my app stopped installing the today extension properly. Following the steps above fixed it again. Also, sometimes it will stop updating with new code. Again, following steps above solved this. Not exactly a stable system. I'm curious to how well this would go with release versions.